# combinations of a length four sublist from four separate lists

Tags: combinations

If I have four lists, `[1,2,15,16], [6,7,10,11], [3,8,9,14], [4,5,12,13]`, how many ways can I get a combination of length four sublists taking one element from each list? For example: `[1,6,3,4],[1,7,8,5],[1,10,9,12]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 choices for which element you choose from the first list, 4 choices for which element you choose from the second list, etc. So $4*4*4*4 = 256$ possible lists.

Comment: thanks. That was what I thought I just wanted to make sure. Cheers.